# does operator overloading in C++ really expect a return value?

Tags: c++

I don't understand the difference between the following snippets. One has a return value and the other doesn't. What really is the difference? When to use what? Looking forward to receiving your answers.

```cpp
bool Distance::operator < (Distance d2) const 
{
    float bf1 = feet + inches/12;
    float bf2 = d2.feet + d2.inches/12;
    return (bf1 < bf2) ? true : false;
}
```

```cpp
operator float() const        //conversion operator
{                          //converts Distance to meters
    float fracfeet = inches/12; //convert the inches
    fracfeet += static_cast<float>(feet); //add the feet
    return fracfeet/MTF; //convert to meters
}
```

Comment: operator T() is a slightly different syntac. T is the returned type

Comment: [OT]: `(bf1 < bf2) ? true : false` can simply be `bf1 < bf2`.

Comment: Both the syntaxes are correct. The former was chosen just to add readability

Comment: That actually *decreases* readability, you have to think even further for something that could be as simple as it is. Remember that readability is much about having things simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last one is a conversion operator, so it is implied that it returns a `float` - you convert your value to this type.

As for `operator<`, it has return type because you can actually make it whatever you like. For instance, `operator<<` for C++ standard library streams do I/O instead of logical shifting.

Comment: `operator<` and `operator<<` are two different things. `operator<<` can return a user-defined type. `operator<` is expected to always return a `bool`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is common, but not required. You can use any return type you want, in case you want to change the meaning of the operator.

Comment: @vil: as for [named operators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/named-operators-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, whenever we overload the operator its developer responsibility to keep operator behavior the same as mentioned in language. As we develop the piece of code that can be used by thousands of users, each doesn't have time to check the implementation of our code.

The principle of least astonishment means that a component of a system should behave in a way that most users will expect it to behave; the behavior should not astonish or surprise users.

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-overloading-and-overload-operators